Deleting photos in QFieldCloud
When I sync my QField projects (mobile) to QGIS (desktop) through QFieldCloud, I would like to be able to delete the synced photos in QFieldCloud. (To save space on my QFieldCloud).
It seems, however, that I am only able to delete photos that have more than one file version and I am NOT able to delete photos that have only one file version.
Is it possible to delete any file from QFieldCloud in a web browser, and if so, how do I do this?
